# How to initialize const array, not readonly, getting error CS0134

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have the following class that is used in conjunction with the data object for [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx):

```
public enum WebUILanguage
{
    EnglishUS,
    German,
    //Actual list is obviously longer
}

[DefaultPropertyAttribute("SaveOnClose")]
public class MyData
{
    private HashSet<WebUILanguage> _SupportedUILanguages = new HashSet<WebUILanguage>(_k_SupportedUILanguages);

    //Area to define all default values    
    const WebUILanguage[] _k_SupportedUILanguages = {   //Error CS0134: A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.
        WebUILanguage.EnglishUS,
        WebUILanguage.German
    };

    [CategoryAttribute("User Interface"),
    DefaultValueAttribute(_k_SupportedUILanguages),
    DescriptionAttribute("Supported user interface languages.")]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public WebUILanguage[] SupportedUILanguages
    {
        get { return _SupportedUILanguages.ToArray(); }
        set 
        { 
            //Do 'set' magic here
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't let me initialize a constant array -- the `_k_SupportedUILanguages` constant in the code above. What is the syntax for that?

PS. Note that I **do not need** a `readonly` array. It must be const!

Comment: No it is not possible in c#

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I noted in my post that I do not need `readonly` definition.

Comment: It doesn't matter you mention it in your post or not. Language doesn't support that. You've to believe that.

Comment: What does a const give you that a readonly doesn't? Other than compile-time constness.. what is your reasoning for not wanting to use readonly?

Comment: And also not readonly array makes the variable only readonly *not the elements of the array*

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: `DefaultValueAttribute` will accept only a const parameter.

Comment: Your question should probably be not about initialization of const array, as it's something not possible with C#, but providing a default value for designer property which is not of a primitive type.